# How do I get access to route parameters in angular 2.0 from components not mapped to a route/router-outlet

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-components

I've got the following routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'metadata/:path', component: MetadataDisplayComponent },
    { path: 'data/:path', component: DataDisplayComponent }
]
```

and here is my AppComponent where the Metadata/Data Display components are injected.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <tree-view></tree-view>  <!-- a component the displays a tree like hierarchy of the path -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `
})
```

So essentially, I ALWAYS want the tree view to be there doing its thing, regardless of metadata/data state, but I need to initialize it based on a parameter in my routes.

Now, my issue is that my my "tree-view" component needs to access the variable ":path" that I have defined in the 2 routes. When I tried the following (inside my tree-view component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector : 'tree-view',
    // etc...
})

export class TreeViewComponent implements OnInit {

    private sub: any;

    contstructor(
        @Inject(ActivatedRoute) private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params['path']);    // this logs "undefined"
        });
    }

    // added this as per the suggestion in the comments
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params['path']);    // this logs "undefined"
        });
    }

    // etc... 

}
```

My attempt at accessing the "path" parameter was unsuccessful, it was console.logged as "undefined".

When I tried the exact same ngOnInit inside my MetadataDisplayComponent, I was able to console.log the path no problem.

I'm almost positive that this is because my TreeViewComponent is not associated with one of my routes, and thus has no access to the route variables. It lives next to, but not within the router outlet.

Is there any way I can make this work out? I recognize that I may have planned the layout in a completely stupid way, and am open to suggestions.

Comment: Your code doesn't show if you inject the ActivatedRoute into the variable this.route.  Are you doing this?

Comment: Yes I am. I attempted to cut out as much code as I could, to highlight the problem. My routing was working with the exact same setup in my MetadataDisplayComponent, so I at least got that much working.

Comment: Try to move your subscription to ngAfterViewInit().

Comment: Just tried it, still undefined

Comment: Not sure why do you need this: @Inject(ActivatedRoute)

Comment: One more thing. Your tree-view component is not handled by the Router.  Try to add a link to the AppComponent and configure a route to open this TreeComponent.

Comment: That's simple, you need to create a service for that, why? Because your `:path` it's only available on `MetadataDisplayComponent`, `DataDisplayComponent` those are the components who have access to that route parameter.

Comment: @YakovFain, I have no idea why I need the Inject, but I couldn't get injecting working otherwise.

Comment: @FabioAntunes, so I essentially cannot do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Nop, you need to create a service that will store your `path and your components `MetadataDisplayComponent` and `DataDisplayComponent` will be responsible for updating that value on the service

Comment: So I store the path value inside a service... how do I pass this service "up" a level and update the TreeViewComponent?

Answer (score 3):

After several hours searching for same thing this is what worked

inside a service/component outside router-outlet

```
this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
      if (val instanceof NavigationEnd) {

        let r = this.route;
        while (r.firstChild) {
          r = r.firstChild;
        }
        r.params.subscribe(params => {
          //do stuff with params['yourParam']
          console.log(params);
        });
      }
    });
```